# my function does not fill any cases in my array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying here to solve a 4x4 skyscraper ([link skyscraper game](https://www.puzzle-skyscrapers.com/))
But the problem is that my function **place** insert 0 number in **tab** and I don't understand why [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqcUe.png) 
 Also I want to specify that I get 0 error: see below why [console log: view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4HBf.png)

Now when I place myself a number for example here 9, it works, in the sense that it fills the cells of the table. But here I get an error on the declaration of x, why?
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pvcw.png) [console log: view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftPt8.png)

I won't post all the code for the sake of readability so here is the main function place:

```
function    place(tab, consign, pos)
{
    var x = Math.floor(pos / 4);
    var y = pos % 4;

    if (tab[x][y] != 0)
        place(tab, consign, pos + 1);
    else
    {
        for (var index = 1; index <= 4; index++)
        {
            tab[x][y] = 9;
            console.log(tab);
            if (colnline_has_no_double(tab, x, y, index))
            {
                if (x % 4 == 3)
                {
                    if (check_top_range(tab, consign, x) && check_bottom_range(tab, consign, x))
                        place(tab, consign, pos + 1);
                }
                if (y % 4 == 3)
                {
                    if (check_left_range(tab, consign, x) && check_right_range(tab, consign, x))
                        place(tab, consign, pos + 1);
                }
                place(tab, consign, pos + 1);
            }
            else
                tab[x][y] = 0;
            if (is_filled_good(tab, consign))
            {
                set_data_in_input(tab);
                return ;
            }
            index++;
        }
        tab[x][y] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling your place function?  What arguments are you passing to it?  I would assume you're working with numbers 1 - 4?  Keep in mind that Math.floor(pos / 4) requires you to pass 16 to get you to 4.  You will never get > 3 for your y value due to the maximum remainder being 1 less than the divisor (4).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I solved it simple adding if (x * x == 16) return; index was > 3, thank you